# Trim trailing newline in one-liner bash alias

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, newlines, whitespace

I'm trying to write a simple alias on my Mac OS X terminal to copy the current working directory.  I have this:

```
alias cpwd="echo \`pwd\` | pbcopy; echo \"Copied \`pwd\`\""
```

Then I can just run the following to copy it:

```
$ cpwd
```

Problem is that `echo pwd` includes the newline at the end.  So when I paste it, it executes immediately (if pasted in a terminal).

All I want to do is strip off the trialing newline, but nothing I find on the internet seems to work for me.  Seen various solution involving `sed`, `awk`, and `cut`, but I can't quite get it.  Seems like it would be easy to do.

Comment: Side note for anyone who saw this post earlier, I had to escape the back ticks in the alias, because `pwd` was actually being run when the aliases were being initialized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I belive this should work :

```
alias cwd="echo -n `pwd` | pbcopy; echo \"Copied `pwd`\""
```

The `-n` says "no new line". Either that or you can always pass the output through `tr` and remove the new line character like that:

```
alias cwd="echo `pwd` | tr -d "\n" | pbcopy; echo \"Copied `pwd`\""
```

I'm not sure if you want to remove the trailing new line char from the first echo or from both - but i guess you can figure it out if it will work for the first one ;)

Comment: Or `echo $(pwd)'\c' | pbcopy; echo \"Copied $(pwd)\"`, where `$(cmd)` is (usually) equivalent to `\`cmd\``, or `pwd | tr -d "\n" | pbcopy; echo …`, since `echo \`xyz\`` (or `echo $(xyz)`) is generally pretty much the same as just plain `xyz` (assuming `xyz` produces _exactly one line_ of output).

Comment: Ha, I was looking in the wrong place for answers - didn't think about `man pwd`.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually... just noticed it isn't in my `man pwd`, so I didn't stand a chance. :-)

Comment: `printf "%s" "$(pwd)"` would work too.

Comment: In case you added this alias for yourself, see my comment on the original question.  You actually need to escape the back ticks.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Mac OS X echo command but if -n argument is provided echo will not output the trailing newline:

-n     do not output the trailing newline

Regards...